# Adding Doma Tools Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just using IntelliJ IDEA(free version) and want to set Doma Tools Plugin in it.

It seems like possible to Eclipse but couldn't figure out how to in IntelliJ IDEA. If you could suggest any way that would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doma Tools Plugin is for Eclipse only.

[Doma Support plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7615-doma-support/update/39191) works in IntelliJ IDEA, but it does not support IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Comment: thats what Im afraid of......But thank you so much for the confirmation!